# How To Change Tab Title To Same Format As Other Pages In WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, tabs, custom-titlebar

I'm using WordPress and I'm trying to change my blog tab name, so it has the same format as the other pages. At the moment when it's on home, it shows up as Home | FootballGamble.co.uk, but when I go onto the betting tips part, it shows up as FootballGamble.co.uk and I want this to be Betting Tips | FootballGamble.co.uk instead. How do I do this?
The site is http://www.footballgamble.co.uk/betting-tips/
Thanks,
Pete

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to call it.
If you look in you theme folder for header.php

```
<title>
<?php if ( !is_front_page() ) { echo wp_title( ' ', true, 'left' ); echo ' | '; }
        echo bloginfo( 'name' ); echo ' - '; bloginfo( 'description',     'display' );  ?> 
</title>
```

Edit this to what you want it to be. To have every page as footballgame write:

```
<title>Footballgamble</title>
```

Or re arrange it to show footballgame | 'page title here'

```
<title>
<?php if ( !is_front_page() ) echo bloginfo( 'name' ); echo ' - '; bloginfo( 'description',     'display'  ' | '{ echo wp_title( ' ', true, 'left' ); }
     );  ?> 
</title>
```

this was from my own header.php so yours may be slightly different